# Total chromatic number of complete bipartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Does anybody know the total chromatic number of the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$?

I've searched for it and I find some assertion that it is sometimes $\Delta(K_{m,n})+1$ and sometimes $\Delta(K_{m,n})+2$. but I didn't find any proof!

Answer (score 2):

Let me start off by a general observation. It is easy to see that $\chi''(K_{m,n}) \leq \Delta + 2$, where $\chi''$ denotes the total chromatic number. It is known that the chromatic index equals the list chromatic index for bipartite graphs. Combining this with the fact that total chromatic number is upper bounded by list chromatic index plus two, we have the claim. (Also, recall bipartite graphs are of class 1, i.e., they are always $\Delta$-edge-colorable).

In fact, the total chromatic number of a complete bipartite graph is either $\Delta+1$ or $\Delta+2$. More specifically, if $m \neq n$, then $\chi''(K_{m,n}) = \Delta + 1 = \max\{m,n\} +1$. Otherwise, $\chi''(K_{m,n}) = \Delta+2 = m+2 = n+2$. A proof is given in [1].

---

[1] H.P. Yap, "Total colourings of graphs", in: Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Springer-Verlag, Germany, 1996.